# NSTableView alternating row colors on Lion

Tags: nstableview

I have an ordinary NSTableView created in a xib. The highlight is set to "regular" with "alternating rows" checked. When I compile my app in Xcode 4.1, the rows do not alternate, and the table is solid white. The same table appeared properly in Xcode 4.0 on Snow Leopard. Unfortunately I don't have a 4.0/Snow Leopard-compiled binary to check on Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a couple such tables in my xib and I played around with checking and unchecking the "alternating rows" checkbox. After a few saves, the rows once again alternate.